# Classification Tree - package rpart and party (R)

Tags: r, tree, classification, rpart, party

I'm trying to build a classification tree in R using the rpart package.
My data has 10 predictor variables (4 of them are categorical, the other 6 numerical).

Sample of my data:

```
> str(rdiabetes)
'data.frame':   559 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ A1c          : num  5.6 5.1 5.6 5.7 6.5 6.4 5.3 5.6 6.2 5.7 ...
 $ BP           : Factor w/ 4 levels "Hypertension",..: 3 1 4 1 3 1 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ BMI          : Factor w/ 4 levels "Normal","Obese",..: 2 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ Age          : int  60 88 76 93 62 80 64 55 57 71 ...
 $ Presc        : int  71 6 0 28 28 39 16 0 0 10 ...
 $ Claims       : int  71 36 109 52 39 44 42 42 39 11 ...
 $ Months       : int  12 11 12 12 12 11 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ Gender       : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Comorbidities: Factor w/ 76 levels "10 or More Dominant Chronic Diseases        ",..: 5 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 17 ...
 $ Monthly.Spend: num  4515 3709 3356 3525 1977 ...
 $ Status2      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Disenrolled",..: 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

And here is my code:

```
#import libraries
library(rpart)

#import dataset
rdiabetes <- read.csv("~/rdiabetes.csv")

set.seed(101)
alpha     <- 0.7 # percentage of training set
inTrain   <- sample(1:nrow(rdiabetes), alpha * nrow(rdiabetes))
train.set <- rdiabetes[inTrain,]
test.set  <- rdiabetes[-inTrain,]

fit <- rpart(Status2 ~ A1c + BP + BMI + Age + Presc + Claims + Months + Gender + Comorbidities + Monthly.Spend, data=train.set)
printcp(fit)
```

These my are results:

```
> printcp(fit)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Status2 ~ A1c + BP + BMI + Age + Presc + Claims + 
    Months + Gender + Comorbidities + Monthly.Spend, data = train.set)

Variables actually used in tree construction:
character(0)

Root node error: 6/391 = 0.015345

n= 391 

  CP nsplit rel error xerror xstd
1  0      0         1      0    0
```

What I'm confused about is this: **Variables actually used in tree construction:
character(0)**
What does this mean? How is it not using any variables in tree construction?

I tried using the summary function for building a tree in the party package as well:

```
> summary(rdiabetes_ctree)
    Length      Class       Mode 
         1 BinaryTree         S4
```

I think it only has one node? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: From the output above it appears that your training data has 391 observations and only six (!) of these have `Status2` = `Disenrolled`. Hence, it is easily possible that none of the available predictor variables explain the variation in `Status2` well enough to generate a split. And given the default constraints for `minsplit` and `minbucket`, you wouldn't get more than one split anyway. So you have to be more careful about model selection and training/evaluation data etc.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thanks very much for your help. This is real data that I wish to analyze. Perhaps instead of using the preassigned Status, I will do k-means clustering with k=2 and assume the clusters are classes...

Comment: You probably only have on the order of 10+/- 2 disenrollments in your entire dataset. There are no methods that will help you overcome such a small set of informative data points.